# Replace bullet in *itemize* \item, but don't replace number in *enumerate* \item

Tags: lists

I'm keeping a document of notes in LaTeX, so I would like todo lists as part of the document (not margin notes, or notes of what to do to the document).

I would quite like to define a set of new commands that work nicely in an numbered list with `\enumerate` or a simple list with `\itemize`, but at the moment I need 2 versions.  Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand{\todoitem}{\item[\Square]~}
\newcommand{\doneitem}{\item[\CheckedBox]~}
\newcommand{\notdoneitem}{\item[\XBox]~}
\newcommand{\todoItem}{\item \Square~}
\newcommand{\doneItem}{\item \CheckedBox~}

\begin{document}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash doneItem} (nice) and \texttt{\textbackslash todoitem} (not nice) in a \texttt{\textbackslash itemize}.
\begin{itemize}
    \doneItem Code the input for the new variables
    \todoitem Code the $y$-mapping
    \item Code the averaging
\end{itemize}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash doneitem} (nice) and \texttt{\textbackslash todoItem} (not nice) in a \texttt{\textbackslash enumerate}.
\begin{enumerate}
    \doneitem Code the input for the new variables
    \todoItem Code the $y$-mapping
    \item Code the averaging
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Is there a way to do the equivalent of my `\todoitem`  inside an `itemize` environment, but my `\todoItem` inside an `\enumerate`?  Can/should I test what environment I'm in?

Comment: Can you not define it the same way as `\newcommand{\todoitem}[1]{\item \Square~#1}` → `\newcommand{\todoItem}[1]{\item \Square~#1}`

Comment: @HarishKumar, that gives me the bullet and then the checkbox as in the 2nd line of my itemize example.

Comment: You want number and then square isn't it? It works.

Comment: @HarishKumar , it works for enumerate, but then doesn't for itemize, I get a bullet then a square, what I want is just the square as given by my todoItem.

Comment: @HarishKumar, exactly, as in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question you are trying to attach to `\doneitem` and `\todoitem` different meanings depending on whether they are called within an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment.

This can be done by moving the code for the definition of the macros to the code executed at the "begin" phase of the environments, instead of giving them a global meaning in the preamble.
The quickest fix can be achieved with this code in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\itemize}{
  \def\notdoneitem{\item[\XBox]~}
  \def\todoitem{\item \Square~}
  \def\doneitem{\item[\CheckedBox]~}
}
\g@addto@macro{\enumerate}{
  \def\todoitem{\item[\Square]~}
  \def\doneitem{\item \CheckedBox~}
}
\makeatother
```

This will "inject" the macro definitions at the beginning of each `itemize` and `enumerate` environments. However this means that these macros will not have a meaning outside the environments.

I am using `\def` instead of `\newcommands` to avoid redefinition errors in case you nest these environments.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, though it needed a little tweak because of legacy stuff from my first attempt (i.e. all the enumerate-specific stuff should be `\item \symbol~` while all the itemize-specific stuff should be `\item[\symbol]`

Answer (score 2):

Let us see the following changes in your code. (Usage: with `item` for `itemize`, with `Item` for `enumerate`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wasysym}
%\newcommand{\todoitem}[1]{\item \Square~#1}
\newcommand{\todoitem}{\item[\Square]~}
%\newcommand{\doneitem}[1]{\item \CheckedBox~#1}
\newcommand{\doneitem}{\item[\CheckedBox]~}
%\newcommand{\notdoneitem}[1]{\item \XBox~#1}
\newcommand{\notdoneitem}{\item[\XBox]~}
%\newcommand{\todoItem}[1]{\item[\Square]#1}
\newcommand{\todoItem}{\item \Square~}
%\newcommand{\doneItem}[1]{\item[\CheckedBox]#1}
\newcommand{\doneItem}{\item \CheckedBox~}

\begin{document}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash doneItem} (nice) and \texttt{\textbackslash todoitem} (not nice) in a \texttt{\textbackslash itemize}.
\begin{itemize}
    \doneItem Code the input for the new variables
    \todoitem Code the $y$-mapping
   \notdoneitem Code the $z$-mapping
    \item Code the averaging
\end{itemize}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash doneitem} (nice) and \texttt{\textbackslash todoItem} (not nice) in a \texttt{\textbackslash enumerate}.
\begin{enumerate}
%    \doneitem Code the input for the new variables
\doneItem Code the input for the new variables
    \todoItem Code the $y$-mapping
    \item Code the averaging
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Unproperly used todoitems left for better understanding.)

Comment: So that's a better way of achieving what I already had, but I still have to call different code if I want it to look nice in itemize vs. enumerate.

Answer (score 2):

Still I am not very sure of your requirements. But you want to use the same command for both environments yielding different results. This can be done with the help of `etoolbox`. Change the `\newcommand*` as you need.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{
    \newcommand*\notdoneitem{\item[\XBox]~}
    \newcommand*\todoitem{\item[\Square]~}
    \newcommand*\doneitem{\item[\CheckedBox]~}
    }
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{
    \newcommand*\todoitem{\item \Square~}
    \newcommand*\doneitem{\item \CheckedBox~}
    }

\begin{document}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash doneItem} (nice) and \texttt{\textbackslash todoitem} (not nice) in a \texttt{\textbackslash itemize}.
\begin{itemize}
    \doneitem Code the input for the new variables
    \todoitem Code the $y$-mapping
    \item Code the averaging
\end{itemize}

Using \texttt{\textbackslash doneitem} (nice) and \texttt{\textbackslash todoItem} (not nice) in a \texttt{\textbackslash enumerate}.
\begin{enumerate}
    \doneitem Code the input for the new variables
    \todoitem Code the $y$-mapping
    \item Code the averaging
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]